# SQL: How do you average data on a monthly basis while only referencing months from a given year?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I am working on a project for one of my Python classes, and I am trying to grab an average monthly snowfall for a given year. In my data set, data collected spans from 2016 to 2017 for many different weather outposts.

This is simply for cleaning up some weather report .csv files with SQLite. I have managed to get the data, traditionally in csv format, into a sqlite format in memory, but my SQL is rusty and I can't get the data to call forward the way I want it to. I have looked through, tried separating the data with a `WHERE DATE < '20170101'` before grouping by date, but I can't even get the data to separate with dates (possibly an issue with how SQL looks for dates and how my dates are punched in, which looks like `12/24/2017`).

Here's what I'm trying to run

```py
con = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE t (STATION, NAME, DATE, AWND, SNOW);")

with open('filteredData.csv','r') as fin:
    # csv.DictReader uses first line in file for column headings by default
    dr = csv.DictReader(fin) # comma is default delimiter
    to_db = [(i['STATION'], i['NAME'], i['DATE'], i['AWND'], i['SNOW']) for i in dr]

cur.executemany("INSERT INTO t (STATION, NAME, DATE, AWND, SNOW) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", to_db)
con.commit()
data = cur.execute("SELECT STATION, NAME, DATE, AWND, AVG(SNOW) FROM t GROUP BY STATION")
```

and I have been trying to add a line in either the `execute` or `executemany` statements to sort through all data entries and filter out before year like so

```py
cur.executemany("INSERT INTO t (STATION, NAME, DATE, AWND, SNOW) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?) WHERE DATE < '20170101'", to_db)
```

I expected the output to show (right now) every location's average snowfall for 2016 (still working on further segregating to average monthly snowfall for every location), but when I add the line above, I get an error. When I run the code without the `WHERE` statement, the code processes fine (and outputs back to a csv like I wanted it to) but only shows averages for every location with no regards to what timeline those averages were taken.

For those curious, the date format in the csv that I'm importing from looks something like this: `12/24/2017`

**EDIT:** I have modified the `execute` statement in the `data` variable to look like

```py
Jan = cur.execute("SELECT STATION, NAME, DATE, AWND, AVG(SNOW) FROM t WHERE (DATE > '2016-01-01' AND DATE < '2016-02-01') GROUP BY STATION")
```

Jan is now reflecting the average for dates `2016-01-01` to `2016-02-01`, which, for the record, appears to actually take the January average snowfall and output it to the CSV. Now, I am working on trying to get February to print after it without overwriting it, of which, simply calling another writerows with another variable seems to just overwrite it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so after working with a friend on the program for a bit, we both figured out that we had to actually call the program into a loop and execute before committing it to the file. Here's what we wrote:

```py
with open("Average2016.csv",'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(['STATION','NAME','DATE','AWND','SNOW'])
    '''
    Fun for loop for generating dates. This uses zfill to pad the dates to 2 decimals
    and checks whether we are on Dec. or not. If we are, skip to next January.
    Then we use an f-string to create a SQL command and execute it and then write
    the return value into the CSV.
    '''
    for x in range(1, 13):
        date1 = '2016-' + str(x).zfill(2) + '-01'
        date2 = '2016-' + str(x + 1).zfill(2) + '-01'
        if (x == 12):
            date2 = '2017-01-01'
        sqlCmd = f"SELECT STATION, NAME, DATE, AWND, AVG(SNOW) FROM t WHERE (DATE >= '{date1}' AND DATE < '{date2}') GROUP BY STATION"
        db_val = cur.execute(sqlCmd)
        writer.writerows(db_val)
```

I wanted to say that this is how I was writing it in the first place, but I think it's called slightly differently than the (frankly messy) way I was calling it before. Thanks everyone else for the help though!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    STATION
  , NAME
  , MIN(DATE)
  , AVG(AWND)
  , AVG(SNOW)
FROM
 t
WHERE 
 DATE < '1/1/17'
GROUP BY
 STATION
```

That SQL statement is invalid by SQL 92+ standards. 
In general when using GROUP BY all non aggregated columns which are used in the `SELECT` clause should also be in the `GROUP BY` clause. 
So the `Name` column should also be in used the `GROUP BY` clause, but that will give you invalid results for your question.

I believe you are looking for this query instead.

```
SELECT 
 t.*
FROM (
  SELECT 
      STATION
    , MIN(DATE) AS min_date
    , AVG(AWND) AS avg_awnd
    , AVG(SNOW) AS avg_snow
  FROM 
   t
  WHERE
   DATE < '1/1/17'
  GROUP BY 
    STATION
) AS t_aggregated
INNER JOIN
 t 
ON
   t_aggregated.STATION = t.STATION
 AND
   t_aggregated.min_date = t.date
```

Comment: Sorry to confuse you with the min(DATE) and avg(AWND), I don't need those. What I am looking to do is simply take my current table with all of the selects and put them in a way where their monthly averages are shown for a given year. I updated my question, so you might want to look at the edit as to how I'm looking to go about this now.

Comment: *"Sorry to confuse you with the min(DATE) and avg(AWND), I don't need those"* in that case the query is harder to solve @SamDeVito i suggest you reading [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) for providing example data and expected results .. The sqlfiddle one has a (browser based) SQLite engine.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
select station, name, strftime('%Y-%m') as yyyymm,
       avg(snow)
from t
group by station, name, strftime('%Y-%m');
```

You can add a `where` clause to limit the data to a particular period of time.  For instance, for 2016:

```
select station, name, strftime('%Y-%m', date) as yyyymm,
       avg(snow)
from t
where date >= '2016-01-01' and
      date < '2017-01-01'
group by station, name, strftime('%Y-%m', date);
```

Comment: Yes, that's very close to what I'm looking for, but I was hoping to delimit it to 2016 and then have every month report the average of snowfall. I have something close in my code now, but I can't get the SQL to call one month's average without averaging everything called. Might make a new post here soon, will link it here if and when i do

Comment: I did not have to strftime like you did, just as a note. I just called the where and it seemed to work. I might try to use the strftime and see if that fixes the issue of everything being overwritten

Comment: @SamDeVito . . . Is there a reason you unaccepted this ansewr?

Comment: It wasn't wrong or anything. This was an answer that I was looking for, but I answered my own question which is why I chose mine as the answer. My answer really fit into the niche of the question, getting averages for every month of the year and then printing it back out. Thank you for the input though :)

Comment: Like I said in comments before, it was close to what I was looking for, but not exactly. That's why I answered it myself and stated what I was looking for there so that way anyone else looking over the post had an idea of how I solved this.